# Empty css using sass-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm trying to use [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/) plugin in my first app, so I can learn and practice with .sass indented files. I have installed the gem, and renamed my application.css.scss to application.css.sass. This is the content of this file:

```
@import bootstrap_and_overrides

body
  background-color #eee
  padding 20px
  margin 0 -20px
```

The fact is that when I inspect the generated css file, all the styles in the @import clause are added to the resulting css file, but not the ones added after the @import ones. I guess it's some how working ok because if I delete the import line, I see my app with no styles at all, and the resulting css file is empty.

Does anyone know why my styles are not added to the resulting css file? Is there a better way of using indented .sass files as default styles? I'm using rails 3.2.3 by the way.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `:` after each attribute:

```
body
  background-color: #eee
  padding: 20px
  margin: 0 -20px
```

Comment: Yes! you're right! I didn't noticed the wrong syntax of my file! Thank you very much!